# Как получить информацию о закупке по ее номеру с сайта госзакупок?

Tags: api, ftp, soap, wsdl

Стоит задача получать информацию с сайта http://zakupki.gov.ru о закупке по номеру.

Судя по тому, что гуглится по этому поводу, все данные(ФЗ №94 и ФЗ №44) можно найти по адресу ftp://free:free@ftp.zakupki.gov.ru

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Все данные лежат в zip архивах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В самих архивах может быть пусто, а может быть много xml, sig, а может и еще каких-нибудь файлов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как разобрать что здесь что? Что лежит в каких папках на ftp. Что и как лежит в xml файлах?
Что бы ответить на этот вопрос написал в тех.поддержку. Они мне ответили так

> Альбомы требований к форматам и файлам (в которых описана в том числе
>   структура каталогов и папок на ФТП-сервере в выгрузке для ИС ФАС)
>   доступны для ознакомления в разделе "Заказчикам -> Документы ->
>   Технорабочие материалы -> Требования к информационному взаимодействию
>   ЕИС с ИС -> Форматы информационного взаимодействия по 223-ФЗ/44-Ф" на
>   Главной странице сайта.

Я пошел туда, куда меня послали
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Скачал архив Схемы 7.5.2
В этом архиве есть xsd файлики с описанием структуры xml файлов. Отлично! С этим все понятно.
Но еще там лежат wsdl файлики.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я плохо понимаю что это такое, но догадываюсь, что они нужны для работы через SOAP. Пришла мысля, что может быть есть API у них?
Полазил в интернетах и понял, что скорее всего эти wsdl`ки нужны для других дел. Интеграция, работа авторизованных пользователей и тд.
А для доступа к данным у нас есть только ftp.

Итого: Для того, чтобы получить закупку по ее номеру, нам нужно выкачать ВСЕ закупки из ftp, засунуть их себе в базу и потом уже работать с ней. 
(Вариант парсить сайт госзакупок через форму поиска не подходит)

Вопрос такой, правда ли то, что мы не можем получить закупку по ее номеру? И должны выкачивать все из ftp? Может быть я что-то упустил? Может все-таки есть какой-то API?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что иметь в виду под "получением информации".
Если нужна основная информация, то да, можно поиском, а можно и через RSS. Там везде rss-ссылки неплохо прописаны. Например можно легко искать по номеру закупки http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/rss?regNumber=0322300103818000003

API там до сих пор не обнаружен, видимо их устраивает заморочка с WDSL, чтобы сторонние сервисы подключались к ним как к вэб-сервису.
Так что либо достаточно информации из RSS, либо нужны подробные данные о запкупке, и тогда либо с сайта выкачивать все страницы, касающиеся закупки (парсить html), либо ftp.

Comment: Если бы была возможность через SOAP, WSDL и тд. получать данные о заявке это бы тоже помогло!

Comment: Нужна вообще вся информация, о заявке, об организаторе, о лотах, всё.

Comment: А там именно такая возможность и есть, насколько видно из описания, и насколько это понятно вообще из принципов работы этих протоколов. Нюанс в том, что эти протоколы они предоставляют, прежде всего (насколько я понимаю) для разработчиков ПО, чтобы через это ПО клиент мог активно работать с закупками, либо для разработчиков коммерческого ПО типа http://www.spark-interfax.ru/ru/features/tenders. Мы раньше этим пользовались. Сейчас просто парсим сайт по нужным нам закупкам, это самый простой вариант получить всю информацию.

Comment: Так я и есть представитель разработчика ПО)))

Comment: Значит, по всей видимости, вам придется копать в сторону вэб-сервисов (wsdl), других нормальных способов получить данные он-лайн у них не видно. Ну кроме парсинга страниц, что далеко не лучший способ. А фтп у них с задержкой пополняется, так что тоже неоптимальный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько мне известно, госзакупки не предоставляют публичных API для своих данных, есть только веб и ftp.

Для "программного" получения каких-либо данных Вам скорее всего потребуется скачать архивы и распарсить xml, которые в них лежат.

Альтернативный вариант - использовать "посредника", например https://dev.gosplan.info.

Ресурс предоставляет API доступ к актуальной информации о закупках нескольких регионов (перечень см. на главной странице). Необходимо пройти процедуру регистрации.

Для отладки можно использовать сервер-"песочницу" https://fz44test.gosplan.info  (регистрация не нужна).

Процесс получения доступа описан в разделе [документация](https://quarter18.gitbook.io/gosplan/)

Пример с вышеуказанного сайта:

```
# Проверяем доступность ресурса
curl https://fz44test.gosplan.info
​
# поиск закупки по номеру
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" \
  https://fz44test.gosplan.info/api/v1/purchases/0372100037420000038
​
# получение плана-графика по номеру в формате JSON
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" \
  https://fz44test.gosplan.info/api/v1/plangraphs2020/202003591000045001
​
# получение плана-графика по номеру в формате XML
curl -H "Content-type: application/xml" \
  https://fz44test.gosplan.info/api/v1/plangraphs2020/202003591000045001.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Информацию о закупке по 44-ФЗ можно получить в XML формате на
https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/printForm/viewXml.html

В качестве параметров можно использовать:

- `printFormId`
- `organizationChangeID`
- `prolongGiveBidId`
- `prolongReviewBidId`
- `protocolCancelID`
- `noticeId`
- `regNumber`
- `protocolId`
- `noticeChangeAuctionDateId`
- `noticeCancelId`
- `structuredProtocolID`

Номер извещения нужно указывать как `regNumber`. Например: https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/printForm/viewXml.html?regNumber=0115300018518000004

Answer (score 0):

Извещение о закупке не по номеру, а по идентификатору в онлайне (XML) выглядит так:
http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/printForm/viewXml.html?noticeId=18090705
Но этот идентификатор не откуда получать :-( Он виден только внутри самого
fcsNotification*.xml (см на картинке printForm/url).
Т.е. остается качать зипованные извещения по маске из каждого регионального раздела и смотреть в наименования файлов, например:

fcsNotificationEP44_0115300018518000004_18090705.xml где:

- **EP44** - тип закупки (у единственного поставщика);
- **0115300018518000004** - номер извещения о закупке;
- **18090705** - идентификатор извещения в ЕИС;

[image: номена и идентификаторы в XML]